# In React-Native when launching the project it gets stuck at Starting: Intent { cmp=com.projectalpha/.MainActivity }

Tags: reactjs, react-native, emulation, launching

The project gets started in cmd but it does not launch the app in the emulator where the emulator is already kept opened. Node does not load as well

extra info: It was working alright until I installed the gesture handler for react (npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler) after this installation I ran react-native run-android and I am stuck from then ever since.

Screenshot from the project :-

These are some screenshot images

[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi58l.png)

[Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv2PD.png)

Logcat when starting the project:

```
2020-10-15 11:52:36.045 1801-13958/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-10-15 11:52:36.045 1801-13958/? W/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM counter does not exist
2020-10-15 11:52:36.046 1801-13958/? W/WakeLock: GCM_CONN_ALARM counter does not exist
2020-10-15 11:52:53.407 14149-14149/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2020-10-15 11:52:53.410 14149-14149/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2020-10-15 11:52:53.443 14149-14149/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-10-15 11:52:53.448 14149-14149/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2020-10-15 11:52:53.470 14149-14149/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2020-10-15 11:52:53.470 14149-14149/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2020-10-15 11:52:53.471 14149-14149/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2020-10-15 11:52:53.482 14149-14149/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
2020-10-15 11:52:53.491 14149-14149/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-10-15 11:52:54.056 14162-14162/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2020-10-15 11:52:54.059 14162-14162/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2020-10-15 11:52:54.091 14162-14162/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-10-15 11:52:54.096 14162-14162/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2020-10-15 11:52:54.124 14162-14162/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2020-10-15 11:52:54.124 14162-14162/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2020-10-15 11:52:54.125 14162-14162/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2020-10-15 11:52:54.136 14162-14162/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
2020-10-15 11:52:54.821 1632-1657/? I/PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dex2oat) on: /data/app/vmdl1909829363.tmp/base.apk pkg=com.projectalpha isa=x86 vmSafeMode=false debuggable=true target-filter=interpret-only oatDir = /data/app/vmdl1909829363.tmp/oat sharedLibraries=null
2020-10-15 11:52:54.834 14175-14175/? W/dex2oat: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-10-15 11:52:54.834 14175-14175/? W/dex2oat: Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) for the command line:
2020-10-15 11:52:54.834 14175-14175/? W/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/app/vmdl1909829363.tmp/oat/x86/base.odex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=interpret-only --swap-fd=9 --debuggable
2020-10-15 11:52:54.835 14175-14175/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --compiler-filter=interpret-only --debuggable
2020-10-15 11:52:55.080 14175-14177/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2020-10-15 11:52:55.162 14175-14177/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2020-10-15 11:52:55.188 14175-14177/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2020-10-15 11:52:56.765 14175-14175/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 1.930s (threads: 4) arena alloc=3KB (3608B) java alloc=4MB (4794264B) native alloc=6MB (7254576B) free=2MB (2706896B)
2020-10-15 11:52:56.771 1632-1645/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.projectalpha appid=10087 user=-1: installPackageLI
2020-10-15 11:52:56.827 1632-1657/? I/PackageManager: Package com.projectalpha codePath changed from /data/app/com.projectalpha-2 to /data/app/com.projectalpha-1; Retaining data and using new
2020-10-15 11:52:56.827 1632-1657/? W/PackageManager: Code path for com.projectalpha changing from /data/app/com.projectalpha-2 to /data/app/com.projectalpha-1
2020-10-15 11:52:56.827 1632-1657/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for com.projectalpha changing from /data/app/com.projectalpha-2 to /data/app/com.projectalpha-1
2020-10-15 11:52:56.930 1632-1657/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
2020-10-15 11:52:56.966 1632-1657/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6220(478KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 21% free, 14MB/18MB, paused 1.193ms total 35.667ms
2020-10-15 11:52:56.980 1632-1657/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.projectalpha appid=10087 user=0: pkg removed
2020-10-15 11:52:56.997 14162-14162/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:56.997 14162-14162/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
2020-10-15 11:52:56.997 1632-1667/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
2020-10-15 11:52:57.008 1632-1667/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
2020-10-15 11:52:57.024 1632-1667/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
2020-10-15 11:52:57.024 12735-12735/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1385 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3011 
2020-10-15 11:52:57.059 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] xva.d(13): PackageMonitorReceiverImpl - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED, [hWtZmkTWngf4PfFqNuNXgZ7rXtIM9k8w23SQhXTifxU]
2020-10-15 11:52:57.059 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] xwb.g(1): Invalidating cached PackageState for com.projectalpha
2020-10-15 11:52:57.064 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] oqg.d(2): Frosting ID looked up on UI thread. Caller should move to a background thread.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.079 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] qhj.s(2): Installer: package com.projectalpha was removed. replacing: true
2020-10-15 11:52:57.080 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] qih.I(12): Installer: Notifying status update. package=com.projectalpha, status=UNINSTALLED
2020-10-15 11:52:57.101 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] oqg.d(2): Frosting ID looked up on UI thread. Caller should move to a background thread.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.106 10598-14188/? I/Finsky: [966] gtc.a(-1): Cancelled 0 ongoing asset module downloads for package com.projectalpha due to a concurrent app update.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.111 10598-14187/? I/Finsky: [965] jid.a(-1): [ContentSync] finished, scheduled=false
2020-10-15 11:52:57.116 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] qih.L(7): Installer: found apps to install. isMultiUserMode=false, apps=[]
2020-10-15 11:52:57.132 10598-14186/? I/Finsky: [964] opt.run(-1): Wrote row to frosting DB: 820
2020-10-15 11:52:57.133 1821-1821/? D/CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:57.136 1821-1821/? D/CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:57.137 1821-1821/? D/CarrierConfigLoader: mHandler: 9 phoneId: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:57.144 10598-14189/? I/Finsky: [967] qvt.C(2): IQ: Notifying installation update. package=com.projectalpha, status=UNINSTALLED
2020-10-15 11:52:57.166 10598-14186/? I/Finsky: [964] opt.run(-1): Wrote row to frosting DB: 821
2020-10-15 11:52:57.177 10598-14189/? I/Finsky: [967] qvt.t(33): IQ: No matching installs to run for jobs: []
2020-10-15 11:52:57.219 1801-14195/? I/Fitness: FitCleanupIntentOperation received Intent android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED [CONTEXT service_id=17 ]
2020-10-15 11:52:57.241 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] xva.d(13): PackageMonitorReceiverImpl - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED, [hWtZmkTWngf4PfFqNuNXgZ7rXtIM9k8w23SQhXTifxU]
2020-10-15 11:52:57.242 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] xwb.g(1): Invalidating cached PackageState for com.projectalpha
2020-10-15 11:52:57.247 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] oqg.d(2): Frosting ID looked up on UI thread. Caller should move to a background thread.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.254 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] alnd.a(3): Do not start WearSupportService due to Wear service optimization
2020-10-15 11:52:57.264 10598-14188/? I/Finsky: [966] gsz.a(-1): Asset module broadcast after update successful for package com.projectalpha. 0 sessions broadcast.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.271 10598-14186/? I/Finsky: [964] opt.run(-1): Wrote row to frosting DB: 822
2020-10-15 11:52:57.272 10598-14187/? I/Finsky: [965] jid.a(-1): [ContentSync] finished, scheduled=false
2020-10-15 11:52:57.274 10598-10598/? I/Finsky: [1] oqg.d(2): Frosting ID looked up on UI thread. Caller should move to a background thread.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.287 1632-1643/? W/BackupManagerService: dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10019
2020-10-15 11:52:57.304 10598-14186/? I/Finsky: [964] opt.run(-1): Wrote row to frosting DB: 823
2020-10-15 11:52:57.336 10750-14196/? I/Auth: [SupervisedAccountIntentOperation] onHandleIntent(): android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
2020-10-15 11:52:57.344 12771-14209/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: Updating corpora: APPS=com.projectalpha, CONTACTS=MAYBE
2020-10-15 11:52:57.356 1632-2080/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } U=0: not found
2020-10-15 11:52:57.358 1632-1643/? W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@1eb3aea
2020-10-15 11:52:57.358 10750-14196/? I/ChromeSync: [Sync,SyncIntentOperation] Handling the intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.projectalpha flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService (has extras) }.
2020-10-15 11:52:57.373 10750-10809/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms
2020-10-15 11:52:57.654 1801-14198/? I/FontLog: Package com.projectalpha has no metadata [CONTEXT service_id=132 ]
2020-10-15 11:52:57.661 10750-10866/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox componentName=null serviceId=36
2020-10-15 11:52:57.668 10750-10857/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=AppsCorpus serviceId=36
2020-10-15 11:52:57.788 10750-14212/? I/GmsCoreXrpcWrapper: Returning a channel provider with trafficStatsTag=12803
2020-10-15 11:52:57.833 10750-10857/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=null serviceId=30
2020-10-15 11:52:57.924 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Usage reports ok 1, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
2020-10-15 11:52:57.929 10750-14212/? I/GmsCoreXrpcWrapper: Returning a channel provider with trafficStatsTag=12803
2020-10-15 11:52:57.946 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
2020-10-15 11:52:57.960 10750-10857/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=null serviceId=36
2020-10-15 11:52:57.971 12771-14209/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: UpdateCorporaTask done [took 627 ms] updated apps [took 626 ms] 
2020-10-15 11:52:57.977 10750-14212/? I/GmsCoreXrpcWrapper: Returning a channel provider with trafficStatsTag=12803
2020-10-15 11:52:58.030 14217-14217/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2020-10-15 11:52:58.034 14217-14217/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2020-10-15 11:52:58.035 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
2020-10-15 11:52:58.038 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Indexing com.google.android.gms-internal.3p:MobileApplication from com.google.android.gms using seqno 160
2020-10-15 11:52:58.042 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Indexing com.google.android.gms-internal.3p:MobileApplication from com.google.android.gms using seqno 160
2020-10-15 11:52:58.076 10750-14212/? I/GmsCoreXrpcWrapper: Returning a channel provider with trafficStatsTag=12803
2020-10-15 11:52:58.081 14217-14217/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-10-15 11:52:58.088 14217-14217/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2020-10-15 11:52:58.095 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Usage reports ok 0, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0
2020-10-15 11:52:58.101 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Indexing com.google.android.gms-apps from com.google.android.gms
2020-10-15 11:52:58.125 14217-14217/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.125 14217-14217/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2020-10-15 11:52:58.126 14217-14217/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2020-10-15 11:52:58.147 14217-14217/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
2020-10-15 11:52:58.169 1632-2081/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.projectalpha/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
2020-10-15 11:52:58.201 14217-14217/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-10-15 11:52:58.210 14227-14227/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.210 14227-14227/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-10-15 11:52:58.218 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Indexing com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-applications_uri from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
2020-10-15 11:52:58.221 1632-1974/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 14227:com.projectalpha/u0a87 for activity com.projectalpha/.MainActivity
2020-10-15 11:52:58.295 1344-1889/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 9592832
2020-10-15 11:52:58.374 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: init start
2020-10-15 11:52:58.374 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /vendor/lib
2020-10-15 11:52:58.374 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /system/lib
2020-10-15 11:52:58.375 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.projectalpha-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
2020-10-15 11:52:58.376 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.projectalpha/lib-main flags = 1]
2020-10-15 11:52:58.377 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
2020-10-15 11:52:58.377 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/vendor/lib flags = 2]
2020-10-15 11:52:58.377 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.projectalpha-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
2020-10-15 11:52:58.377 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.projectalpha/lib-main flags = 1]
2020-10-15 11:52:58.378 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.projectalpha/lib-main
2020-10-15 11:52:58.380 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: deps mismatch on deps store: regenerating
2020-10-15 11:52:58.380 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: so store dirty: regenerating
2020-10-15 11:52:58.419 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Indexing done com.google.android.gms-apps
2020-10-15 11:52:58.438 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libevent-2.1.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.438 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libevent_core-2.1.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libevent_extra-2.1.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libflipper.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libimagepipeline.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libjsc.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libnative-filters.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libnative-imagetranscoder.so: deferring to libdir
2020-10-15 11:52:58.439 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
2020-10-15 11:52:58.440 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: Finished regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
2020-10-15 11:52:58.440 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: starting syncer worker
2020-10-15 11:52:58.441 10750-14212/? I/Icing: Indexing done com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-applications_uri
2020-10-15 11:52:58.459 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.projectalpha/lib-main (from syncer thread)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.459 14227-14227/com.projectalpha V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: not releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.projectalpha/lib-main (syncer thread started)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.459 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: init finish: 4 SO sources prepared
2020-10-15 11:52:58.460 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: init exiting
2020-10-15 11:52:58.464 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: init exiting
2020-10-15 11:52:58.464 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: About to load: libjscexecutor.so
2020-10-15 11:52:58.465 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.projectalpha/lib-main
2020-10-15 11:52:58.465 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/app/com.projectalpha-1/lib/x86
2020-10-15 11:52:58.465 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /system/vendor/lib
2020-10-15 11:52:58.465 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /system/lib
2020-10-15 11:52:58.466 14227-14227/com.projectalpha W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
2020-10-15 11:52:58.468 14227-14227/com.projectalpha E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so result: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:58.469 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: init exiting
2020-10-15 11:52:58.482 14227-14227/com.projectalpha D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-10-15 11:52:58.498 2099-2201/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaaf052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaf03560)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.511 14227-14247/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: About to load: libfbjni.so
2020-10-15 11:52:58.511 14227-14247/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/data/com.projectalpha/lib-main
2020-10-15 11:52:58.511 14227-14247/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/app/com.projectalpha-1/lib/x86
2020-10-15 11:52:58.511 14227-14247/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /system/vendor/lib
2020-10-15 11:52:58.511 14227-14247/com.projectalpha D/SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /system/lib
2020-10-15 11:52:58.512 14227-14247/com.projectalpha E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so result: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.facebook.flipper.android.EventBase>: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so result: 0
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at void com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(java.lang.String, int, android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy) (SoLoader.java:825)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at boolean com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy) (SoLoader.java:673)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at boolean com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(java.lang.String, int) (SoLoader.java:611)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at boolean com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (SoLoader.java:559)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at boolean com.facebook.soloader.NativeLoaderToSoLoaderDelegate.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (NativeLoaderToSoLoaderDelegate.java:25)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at boolean com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (NativeLoader.java:44)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at void com.facebook.jni.HybridData.<clinit>() (HybridData.java:34)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.516 14227-14248/com.projectalpha I/art:     at void com.facebook.flipper.android.FlipperThread.run() (FlipperThread.java:25)
2020-10-15 11:52:58.518 14227-14247/com.projectalpha E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FlipperEventBaseThread
    Process: com.projectalpha, PID: 14227
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so result:
```

Comment: Open the emulator manually from android studio and check what is the error there.

Comment: I attached the logcat result above when I start the application @PrateekThapa

Comment: Does this =>  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28750#issuecomment-619594353 resolve your error?

Comment: I was unclear of the instruction, so I researched how to clean gradle cache and typed in  "gradlew cleanBuildCache", but the result was the same so then next I typed in "gradelw clean", now my project is not even starting, I unintentionally cleaned the gradle file and now this error comes up -    "error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details"

Comment: Okay I solved that issue now I am back again to square 1, so I tried cleaning the cache of gradle, it did not solve the issue. I would appreciate it if you could help me through since I am a beginner and I just started learning react

Comment: Since you're beginner to `react-native`, why are you using `react-native-gesture-handler` library anyway?

Comment: I am learning from a course, so I was just following it, but I solved the issue by creating a new project and this time I made it an expo project and moved all my javascript files to the new project